# Android - AlertDialog within onContextItemSelected does not work

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a following pseudo-code.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem aItem) {
      switch(aItem.getItemId()) {
           case A: {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                  .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                  .setTitle("Delete")
                  .setMessage("Delete?")
                  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             // do stuff A...
                       }
                  });

                  // do stuff B...

                  return true;
           }
      }
  }
```

The problem is that it never shows the alert dialog. However, it does things as stated in "do stuff B..."

Does anyone know why AlertDialog is now showing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to .create() .show() will solve the problem :)

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
              .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
              .setTitle("Delete")
              .setMessage("Delete?")
              .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                   }
              }).create();
dialog.show();
```

And when you don't need it anymore you can dismiss() it.

**Edit:** sorry. forgot .create() :)

Comment: I guess it has happened to all of us sometime.

Comment: totally! and more than just once :) i stopped counting how often i forgot to call .show() and wondered, until i found the problem and got angry at myself :D

Comment: Hello, thank you very for your answer. That worked. I feel like an idiot after suffering for couple days on this. lol. Well, I guess I will remember next time. (I'm an android newb ;) ) Thank you!